# Flash banner, crossdomain and XML loading

Tags: flash, crossdomain.xml, banner

I want to create flash banner with XML content, and host it on my site with crossdomain.xml, and then share banner code with other sites for banner exchange.

So, everything is on my server.

Will loading banner, on other sites, load XML from my server, if both banner and XML resides on the same server, but banner is loaded on the other site?

Sorry, my english sucks, hope You will understood :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of a crossdomain.xml is to allow a flash hosted on one server communicating with another, so if the banner is loaded from the *same* server that hosts the xml you won't need one.

Comment: It seams that flash is looking for crossdomain.xml on server where is loaded :(

Comment: It works :)
But crossdomain.xml must be on server where banner and XML are.
Thanks